# searching a specific string in a .csv file with bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to search through a .csv file and find a specific fixed string and filter it out. The string repeats in the same file just with different values.

I'm thinking of something like: `grep -Fo  "ILikeTheColor": "Blue" test.csv`

So I just want an iterative output of matching strings in the console but the problem are the multiple "" and maybe the space; is there a way to search for that exact specific string?

Comment: You have to specify a [regular expression](https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/ArubaOS_63_Web_Help/Content/ArubaFrameStyles/ESI/Basic_Regular_Expression.htm)  for your pattern. Since you don't say what characters can be between the colon and the colour, and what character can be after the colour, it's hard to recommend a concrete pattern.

Comment: *Is there a way to search for that exact specific string?* Yes: surround it with single quotes: `'"ILikeTheColor": "Blue"'` to disable expansion

Comment: @user1934428 It is in a huge file which looks before and after like this: 
true, `"ILikeTheColor": "Blue"}`, "loc
So I am just interested in the `part`. So I need to find a RegEx, I'll see what I can set up, thanks!

@joH1 unfortunately '"ILikeTheColor": "Blue"' I don't get an output if I write it like that..

Comment: Of course - the command you posted does not make much sense. It searches the string `ILikeTheColor:` in the files `Blue` and `test.csv`. For a start, you could use the pattern `grep '"ILikeTheColour": *"[^"]*"' test.csv`, but I don't quite understand why you have that curly brace after `"Blue"`, if this is really a CSV file. Perhaps you could post the whole line of the file which contains the colour definition.

Comment: @user1934428     Thanks a lot for your help, while it is an .csv and I'm working with a tone of sensitive data there is no real line 1,2,..,etc. The curly brace is fix so it will be in the regex. In more detail around that line it looks like that=  "ILikeRobots": "", "ILikeTheRain": true, `"ILikeTheColor": "Blue"},` "Country": {"UK": "true", "state": "Irland", "..." I replaced the input to work with it so there is no real meaning or sense in them but a string is a string what matters to catch is around it :D

Comment: I suggest than that you add this information to the question (not in a comment), because it is important for understanding. Best would be to past the relevant part of the input file (at least including one line before and after). Also, post the exact command you use to find the item (I suggested to construct a suitable regex for this).